# Ошибка EntityNotFoundException в Java, Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Получаю `EntityNotFoundException`, когда пытаюсь получить ревизии класса `Action` для поля `Plan` для некоторых значений `Action`. Хотя `planId` присутствует и в таблице `Action`, и во всех ревизиях `Action`.

Метод:

```
private Optional<Revision<Integer, Action>> getLatestActionRevisionBeforeDate(final Long id, final LocalDate date) {
    final var beforeInstant = date.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
    return this.actionRepository.findRevisions(id).stream()
        .filter(rev -> rev.getMetadata().getRequiredRevisionInstant().isBefore(beforeInstant))
        .max(Comparator.naturalOrder());
  }
```

Классы:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@DynamicUpdate
@Entity(name = "new_action")
@Accessors(chain = true)
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "fetch.whole.action",
    attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "plan"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "actionAdditional"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "status", subgraph = "action.status.translations"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "evidences", subgraph = "action.evidence.documents")},
    subgraphs = {
        @NamedSubgraph(name = "action.status.translations", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "translations")),
        @NamedSubgraph(name = "action.evidence.documents", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "documents"))
    })
@Audited
@AuditOverride(forClass = UpdatableEntity.class)
public class Action extends UpdatableEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 4489013915376063513L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String title;

  @Lob
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String description;

  @Exclude
  @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
  @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
  private ActionStatus status;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private boolean isOnRisk;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private boolean isValidated;

  @Lob
  private String comment;

  @Exclude
  @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
  @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
  private Plan plan;

  private LocalDateTime scheduledDateTime;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private LocalDate deadlineDate;

  private LocalDateTime statusUpdatedDateTime;

  @Exclude
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "action", cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @NotAudited
  private Set<Evidence> evidences = new HashSet<>();

  @Exclude
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "action", cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @NotAudited
  private ActionAdditional actionAdditional;

  public Action setEvidences(@NonNull final Set<Evidence> evidences) {
    this.evidences = new HashSet<>(evidences);
    evidences.forEach(evidence -> evidence.setAction(this));
    return this;
  }

  public Action setActionAdditional(final ActionAdditional actionAdditional) {

    if (actionAdditional != null) {
      actionAdditional.setAction(this);
    }

    this.actionAdditional = actionAdditional;

    return this;
  }

  public Action add(@NonNull final Evidence evidence) {
    this.evidences.add(evidence);
    evidence.setAction(this);
    return this;
  }

  public Action remove(@NonNull final Evidence evidence) {
    this.evidences.remove(evidence);
    evidence.setAction(null);
    return this;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) {
      return false;
    }
    final Action action = (Action) o;
    return this.getId() != null && Objects.equals(this.getId(), action.getId());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return this.getClass().hashCode();
  }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "new_plan")
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Audited
@AuditOverride(forClass = UpdatableEntity.class)
public class Plan extends UpdatableEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -424662028473956250L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private boolean isLaunched;

  private String diagnosis;

  @Column(name = "external_location_id")
  private String locationId;

  @Column(name = "external_audit_id")
  private String auditId;

  @Column(name = "external_company_id")
  private String companyId;

  @Column(name = "external_address_id")
  private String addressId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = EAGER)
  @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
  @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name = "external_location_id", referencedColumnName = "LOCATION_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
      @JoinColumn(name = "external_company_id", referencedColumnName = "COMPANY_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
      @JoinColumn(name = "external_address_id", referencedColumnName = "ADDRESS_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  })
  private ExtLocation externalLocation;

  @OneToOne
  @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
  @JoinColumn(name = "external_company_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private ExtCompany extCompany;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private LocalDate startDate;

  private LocalDate kickOffDate;

  private LocalDate plannedFinishingDate;

  @Convert(converter = SponsorsToJsonConverter.class)
  private List<Sponsor> sponsors;

  @Exclude
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "plan", cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
  private Close close;

  @Exclude
  @ManyToOne(fetch = EAGER)
  @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
  private Category category;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = EAGER)
  @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
  private PlanStatus status;

  @Exclude
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "plan", cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = EAGER)
  @NotAudited
  private Set<Action> actions = new HashSet<>();

  @Exclude
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "plan", cascade = {ALL}, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = LAZY)
  @NotAudited
  private Set<ManuallyCreatedNonConformity> nonConformity = new HashSet<>();

  @Exclude
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "plan", cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = LAZY)
  @NotAudited
  private List<Milestone> milestones = new LinkedList<>();

  @Exclude
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "plan", cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = EAGER)
  @NotAudited
  private Set<Extension> extensions = new HashSet<>();

  @ManyToOne(fetch = EAGER)
  @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
  private PlanOrigin origin;

  public Plan add(@NonNull final Action action) {
    this.actions.add(action);
    action.setPlan(this);
    return this;
  }

  public Plan add(@NonNull final ManuallyCreatedNonConformity nonConformity) {
    this.nonConformity.add(nonConformity);
    nonConformity.setPlan(this);

    return this;
  }

  public Plan add(@NonNull final Extension extension) {
    this.extensions.add(extension);
    extension.setPlan(this);
    return this;
  }

  public Plan add(@NonNull final Milestone milestone) {
    this.milestones.add(milestone);
    milestone.setPlan(this);
    return this;
  }

  public Plan setMilestones(@NonNull final List<Milestone> milestones) {
    this.milestones = new LinkedList<>(milestones);
    this.milestones.forEach(milestone -> milestone.setPlan(this));
    return this;
  }

  public Plan actualizeMilestones() {
    this.milestones.forEach(milestone -> milestone.setPlan(this));
    return this;
  }

  public Plan addAllExtensions(@NonNull final Set<Extension> extensions) {
    this.extensions.addAll(extensions);
    this.extensions.forEach(extension -> extension.setPlan(this));
    return this;
  }

  public Plan addAllActions(@NonNull final Collection<Action> actionsToAdd) {
    this.actions.addAll(actionsToAdd);
    actionsToAdd.forEach(action -> action.setPlan(this));
    return this;
  }

  public Plan addAllNonConformity(@NonNull final Collection<ManuallyCreatedNonConformity> nonConformity) {
    this.nonConformity.addAll(nonConformity);
    nonConformity.forEach(item -> item.setPlan(this));
    return this;
  }

  public Plan addAllMilestones(@NonNull final Collection<Milestone> milestonesToAdd) {
    this.milestones.addAll(milestonesToAdd);
    milestonesToAdd.forEach(milestone -> milestone.setPlan(this));
    return this;
  }

  public Plan remove(@NonNull final Action action) {
    this.actions.remove(action);
    action.setPlan(null);
    return this;
  }

  public Plan setClose(final Close close) {
    this.close = close;
    Optional.ofNullable(close)
        .map(close1 -> close1.setPlan(this));
    return this;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) {
      return false;
    }
    final Plan plan = (Plan) o;
    return this.id != null && Objects.equals(this.id, plan.id);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return this.getClass().hashCode();
  }
}
```

Comment: `Хотя planId присутствует и в таблице Action, и во всех ревизиях Action` . А как насчет таблиц `Plan` (при наличии аннотации `@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)`)и ее табилицы аудита (если убрать аннотацию, то будет смотреть в таблицу аудита), там есть соответствующие значения?

Comment: Есть случаи, когда в ауд таблице для плана отсутствуют соответствующие значения, но есть и где присутствуют, но в обоих случаях получаю эксепшн

Comment: Вообще, как мне кажется, главная проблема, что получаю ексепшн, где есть все аудиты

Comment: проблема решена просто апдейтом версии envers до более поздней.